# Howto install a nodejs app on Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, droplet

I try to install https://github.com/aepsilon/turing-machine-viz on a Digital Ocean doplet.

I did

```
git clone https://github.com/aepsilon/turing-machine-viz
cd ./turing-machine-viz
npm install
npm start
```

But I'm unable to get my web page. Any clue ?

Comment: Do you have any error messages?

Comment: Not really. Just "Unable to reach...". Like the address doesn't exists.

Comment: What's the address you're trying to access? In particular, which port are you using?